# Printing StringBuffer JOptionPane

Tags: java, ascii, stringbuilder, joptionpane

I'd like to start by saying thank you to the stackoverflow community and all the great people who answer these questions.  Much more often than not, I find my answer by reading and not typing, however I am pressed for time, as this is a homework assignment that must completed in the next couple of days. So here is my problem.

Intro To Programming > ASCII Art Project > I want to Print it to a window, not just the boring console.

This is what I have come up with so far but the image doesn't look correct in the JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (It does look as intended when that same stringbuilder is printed to the console):

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class R2D2 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {    
    boolean test = false;//Create and initialize boolean variable; later used to break out of the Do While loop.

  do
  {
     String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Who is everyone's favorite Droid?");//GUI asking for 'favorite droid' input.

     if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("R2D2") || name.equalsIgnoreCase("R2"))//Sets boolean test to true if the user inputs the correct answer ie 'R2D2' or 'R2', not case sensitive. 
     {
        test = true;
     }

     else
     {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nope! Try Again...Dummy.");//Chides the user.
     }
  }
  while (test == false);//Continues back to the top if the user doesn't answer correctly.


  String l0  = new String("                _____________                  ");//In lines 14,15,16 the escape used to place the backslash has no real
  String l1  = new String("               /_/_/_/_/_/_/_\\                ");//effect because there isn't any ASCII art to the right of the escape (oh no, I just  
  String l2  = new String("              /_/_/_/_/_/_/_/_\\               ");//realized you probably won't like how I am spanning lines with the single line commentor).
  String l3  = new String("             /      _______    \\              "); 
  String l4  = new String("            /      /  (\"\") \\    \\          ");//The first double quote is shifted one character to the right, the second double quote is shifted two characters to the right, the second backslash (of the first backslash grouping) is shifted three characters to the right, and the second backslash (of the second backslash grouping) is shifted four characters to the right.  It's kinda lonely out here.  
  String l5  = new String("           /      /_________\\    \\           ");//1 escape in R2's body results in his right edge being shifted to the right one character.
  String l6  = new String("          /                       \\           ");
  String l7  = new String("         /              0   (O)    \\          ");//Again no real effect seen from the escapes on lines 19, 20, 21.
  String l8  = new String("        /                           \\         ");
  String l9  = new String("   ____(       ---------------       )____     ");
  String l10 = new String("  |    |       ---------------       |    |    ");
  String l11 = new String("  |    |                             |    |    ");
  String l12 = new String("  |    |                             |    |    ");
  String l13 = new String("  |    |       ---------------       |    |    ");
  String l14 = new String("  |    |       ===============       |    |    ");
  String l15 = new String("  |    |                             |    |    ");
  String l16 = new String("  |    |                             |    |    ");
  String l17 = new String("  |    |       ---------------       |    |    ");
  String l18 = new String("  |    |       ===============       |    |    ");
  String l19 = new String("  |    |                             |    |    ");
  String l20 = new String("  |    |                             |    |    ");
  String l21 = new String("  |    |                             |    |    ");
  String l22 = new String("  |    |                             |    |    ");
  String l23 = new String("  )    |_____________________________|    (    ");
  String l24 = new String(" /     \\                             /     \\ ");
  String l25 = new String("(_______)                           (_______)  ");


  String[] lineholder = {l0,l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7,l8,l9,l10,l11,l12,l13,l14,l15,l16,l17,l18,l19,l20,l21,l22,l23,l24,l25};


  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  for(int i=0 ; i < lineholder.length; i++)
  {
     sb.append(lineholder[i] + "\n");
  }

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sb.toString());

  System.out.println(sb.toString());


  System.out.println("\n\n\n//In Your Best Robot Voice");//Intentionally left comment break visible for effect
  System.out.println("End Of Program");


   }
}
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks again.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the malformed output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem may be one of font, since the JOptionPane will not display the data as a monospaced font that would be required.

One option is to use a JTextArea where you set the font to monospaced:

```
  JTextArea tArea = new JTextArea(lineholder.length, 50);
  tArea.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 10));
  tArea.setText(sb.toString());
  JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tArea);
  //!! JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sb.toString());
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, scrollPane);
```

---

Theoretically you could set the JOptoinPane's font via

```
UIManager.put("OptionPane.font", new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 10));
```

But I couldn't get this to work.

---

Edit, or if you want to get rid of the JScrollPane (habit for me to use it) and the white background:

```
  JTextArea tArea = new JTextArea(lineholder.length, 50);
  tArea.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 10));
  tArea.setText(sb.toString());
  tArea.setOpaque(false);
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, tArea);
```

---

As always, if anything in this answer confuses you, or if it doesn't fully answer your question, then please post a comment to this question asking for clarification.

Comment: That was it Hovercraft, thank you!  If I could just review so as to further my understanding of what was accomplished here:

Comment: The console prints with a monospaced font, the JOptionPane comes default with a non-monospaced font which caused the alteration of my ASCII art.  In theory we could have changed the JOptionPane font to monospace, but for some reason this wouldn't work for you.  Instead we created a JTextArea with constructor of ( rows, columns). We then set the font of the JTextArea by passing in a new font object constructed by (font facename MONOSPACE, style PLAIN, size 10). We then passed in the populated, monospaced, non-opaque JTextArea into JOptionPane's showMessageDialog.  Is that correct?